# Get list of hyperlinks of all audio files in a shared folder

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, synchronization, shared-directory

I work in audio.
I would like to create an excel spreadsheet that takes all audio files in a directory and outputs them into a list with hyperlinks, so we can quickly reference each tracks and add notes and comments on other columns in the spreadsheet.
All our files are stored on Sync, a shared folder system akin to Dropbox or Google Drive.

I've succeeded with the following VBA code, found online:

```
Sub listfiles()
Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xFSO As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim xFiDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Set xFiDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFiDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xPath = xFiDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Set xFiDialog = Nothing
    If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        I = I + 1
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(I, 1), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that even though the directory is that of a shared folder, other members of my team can't use the spreadsheet since the directory contains specific information at the beginning pertaining to my PC.

So there are two ways I was thinking of fixing this:

1. To split the path in two parts : Personal System path + Shared Folder path
   Would it be possible for the program to ask these separatly and just append both into a global path so that way it would circumvent the error of another user not having the correct path ? Se we'd have a "get local path" part, a "get only shared folder path" part and then an extra step where the total path would be "local path + shared folder path".
2. The Sync Files also exist online, irrespective of the user's local shared folder. Would it be possible to enter as a directory in VBA the online link of the shared folder and comb through the files and get the hyperlink list in the same way ?

Is there a simpler, more elegant solution to it that I'm not seeing ?

Furthermore, if there was a way for that spreadsheet to automatically update itself each time a member of the team uploads a new file, it would be optimal.
I'm open to using something else than VBA, I don't know the language, however I do know python in a very basic way.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide,

Dany

Comment: Is it related to the user name? If yes, you might want to have a look into [environment variables](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s387/environment-variable-vba.htm) such as `Environ("USERPROFILE")` which will give you something that vary accoss computers.

Comment: I looked into it, thanks! I think it might be able to execute the 1st solution I had in mind

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to post your answer here to help the next person with a similar problem.

Comment: Actually, what I ended up doing was taking the original code, but turning the Sub header into an "Auto_Open()".

That way, each time you open the execl, the dialog to choose the path prompts and then each user can enter his own path.

It's not ideal but given my situation this workaround works just fine for my usage!